# WordPress помогите с решением или поиском плагина

Tags: wordpress

Суть вопроса в том что нам нужно передать запрос в url и сохранить его.

Допустим у нас при загрузке страница сайта предлагает выбрать город:

- Днепропетровск
- Киев
- Харьков

При выборе города у нас генерирует url:

- `http://example.com/dnepr`
- `http://example.com/kiev`
- `http://example.com/harkov`

Этот url должен сохраняться при переходе по другим ссылкам, покажу на примере перехода на страницу категории (рубрики) `http://example.com/dnepr/category/`

Соответственно я проверяю url на наличие того или иного города и в зависимости от этого генерирую некий контент на страницах.

Прошу у вас помощи, направьте на нужный путь или посоветуйте плагин.

По сути принцип как у любой мультиязичности.

Comment: Никто вам не подскажет. Потому что URL - это пол дела. Вот например, контент будет полностью одинаковый? то есть набор страниц. а Поддомены не подойдут? гораздо проще все будет

Comment: При таком подходе Вам придется перепиливать всю систему Вордпресс. Ведь если для таких URL ВП будет выдавать вам 404. Придется делать rewrite в htaccess. Все пермалинки в шаблоне тоже придется перерабатывать. Короче - беда. Подумайте о другом подходе.

Comment: Нужно менять правила переадресации https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте города поддоменами. Конечно покопаться и покопировать свой сайт придётся, но потом в дальнейшем, Вы сможете малейший нюанс изменять в определённом городе, по отдельности от других городов.

Comment: Добавлю только ссылку к ответ, потому что согласен. https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8

Answer (score 0):

Алгоритм действий примерно такой:

- Меняете правила переадресации
  https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite.
- Используя фильтр add_filter('query_vars'), нужно разрешить свой GET параметр.     Сможете потом достучаться до него используя get_query_var('parametr_name')